# Making sure only one $http GET is issued using angular's $httpBackend testing utilities

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I want to unit test an angular service which caches $http GET requests.

In order to do that, I want to make sure only one $http GET is issued.

Here is my unit test:

```
it('should use cache', inject(function (messageService, $httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/message/find-latest-messages').respond([new Message({id: 42, text: 'Hello dude'})]);

    var responses = [];

    //Cache miss (first request)
    messageService.findLatestMessages().then(function(results){
        responses = results.data;
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(responses).toEqual([new Message({id: 42, text: 'Hello dude'})]);

    //Cache hit (second request)
    messageService.findLatestMessages().then(function(results){
        responses = results.data;
    });

   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();

}));
```

The above test passes.

However, what worries me is that when I change the second call to `messageService` to:

```
    //Does not use the cache because explicitly told to do so
    messageService.findLatestMessages({refresh: true}).then(function(results){
        responses = results.data;
    });

    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
```

It still passes whereas I know there's an outstanding request...

This is proved by that fact that the modified test below fails with:

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
```

Failing test (second call to `messageService`):

```
    //Uses cache and therefore no $http is issued
    messageService.findLatestMessages().then(function(results){
        responses = results.data;
    });

    $httpBackend.flush();
```

So how can I use angular test utilities in order to ensure that only one $http GET was issued - which should be the case with my cached service above?

For you information here are relevant portions of the tested service:

```
    function get(url, options, cacheKey, cacheOptions) {
        if ((!cacheOptions || !cacheOptions.refresh) && messageCache[cacheKey]) {
            return $q.when(messageCache[cacheKey]);
        }

        var req = $http.get(url, options);

        if (cacheKey) {
            req.then(function (param) {
                messageCache[cacheKey] = param.data;
            }).then(broadcast);
        }
        return req;
    }
    ...
    findLatestMessages: function (cacheOptions) {
       return get('/api/message/find-latest-messages', {transformResponse: transformMessagesResponse}, 'latestMessages', cacheOptions);
    }
```

**Edit**: I have found the following hack:

```
expect(function () {
    $httpBackend.flush()
}).toThrow(new Error('No pending request to flush !'));
```

However, I am not satisfied with this way of ensuring the number of http GETs and would like a better solution...

Answer (score 1):

`$httpBackend.expectXXX()` returns a `requestHandler` ([type definitions here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts)) that enables you to pass a function to `respond`. This could be used to enforce a maximum number of calls if you so wished, like so:

```
const maximumInvocations = 1;
let invocations = 0;
$httpBackend.expectGET('/foo').respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
  invocations++;
  if(invocations >= maximumInvocations) {
    return [500];
  }
  return [200];
});
```

This is not the neatest thing and its dubious as to whether you need it or not. You could probably reduce the amount of boilerplate here by creating a helper function or using existing functions such as [lodash.after](https://lodash.com/docs#after).

Also worth mentioning that the returned `requestHandler` can have *another* `respond` assigned to it after-the-fact if you have some way of verifying that it was only called once. For example (again, messy):

```
const requestHandler = $httpBackend.expectGET('/foo').respond(function (method, url, data, headers) {
  // Next response will return a 500 error
  requestHandler.respond(500, {});
  return [200];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DanPantry. I am sure I am missing something obvious here... Maybe my test could be changed and simplified... Also: do you know why my call to `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();` has no effect?

Comment: The solution you suggested is interesting and I am going to look into it but it does not make my test more readable...

Comment: From your description it sounds like your second call to `messageService.findLatestMessages()` is never hitting the `$http` service; reinforced by the fact that you get the `no outstanding request to flush!` error. That would explain why `verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` doesn't appear to do anything. While there *should* be an outstanding request, there isn't; is there something funky going on inside `findLatestMessages`?

Comment: Well, yes, it's not readable and I mentioned that as a caveat. Unfortunately there's no baked-in method for asserting the number of times something has been called in `$httpBackend`, most likely because that is quite brittle and is easily solved by using something like `sinon.spy()` or something that I posted above.

Comment: Regarding `$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();`, what makes me think it has no effect is that when I explicitly tell my service not to use the cache and therefore to issue two GETs, the `verifyNoOutstandingRequest` is ignored. See my paragraph starting with *However what worries me...*

Comment: I read your question. `verifyNoOutstandingRequest()` is not *ignored* - it checks whether or not there are any pending requests that should have been flushed. That method is not being ignored, there just *isn't* a pending request - you can see that from your `$httpBackend.flush()` call error.